Get URL for page where the logs will appear for the current job
In a GitHub Actions workflow there are context variables for the current run ID and the current job name. These are sufficient to build a URL like this:
https://github.com/REPO/actions/runs/RUN_ID

This URL takes you to the following page:

I'd like to take the user to the page that would be accessed by clicking the "Import" job in the screenshot above, which has a URL like this:
https://github.com/REPO/actions/runs/RUN_ID/job/JOB_ID

This page looks like this:

I cannot find this JOB_ID anywhere in the context variable documentation. There is github.job, but this gives a job name like "import", which leads to a 404 if I put it in the URL above. There is also job.container.id, but this seems to be an unrelated ID, and doesn't work.
How can I construct the URL for the page in the second screenshot above?

This question is similar to: Obtain job id from a workflow run using contexts. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

The GitHub CLI provides a convenience function for this to inspect a workflow run:
gh run view "$GITHUB_RUN_ID"

You can request the jobs with
gh run view "$GITHUB_RUN_ID" --json jobs

which returns something like
{
  "jobs": [
    {
      "completedAt": "2024-09-04T16:55:29Z",
      "conclusion": "skipped",
      "databaseId": 29683129691,
      "name": "Some name",
      "startedAt": "2024-09-04T16:55:29Z",
      "status": "completed",
      "steps": [],
      "url": "https://github.com/{owner}/{repo}/actions/runs/{runID}/job/{jobID}"
    }
  ]
}

Since you're interested in the job URL, you could get it directly with something like
gh run view "$GITHUB_RUN_ID" --json jobs \
    --jq '.jobs | map(select(.name == "Import")) | first.url'

I'm not sure at which point this becomes available during a run, though.

first.url will return a GitHub API url in the form https://api.github.com/repos/REPO/actions/jobs/JOB_ID. This url can not be used to view the web page of the job. Instead you can request first.id This will return JOB_ID that can be used in the web url suggested: https://github.com/REPO/actions/runs/RUN_ID/job/JOB_ID

@DeltaGeorge No, it's in the form as shown in my example, linking to the web page. How did you test?

@DeltaGeorge Notice that I'm not making a direct API call to get the job object, which looks more like what you describe.

Yes, your are correct. In fact, the url is in your answer! I tested via an API instead, also using GitHub CLI: gh api /repos/$repo/actions/runs/$run_id/jobs It looks like GitHub CLI commands are not just wrapping the API. They are targeting different use cases and produce subtly different JSON payloads.

Hmm when I run "gh run view $RUN_ID --json jobs" I get Unknown JSON field: "jobs" and then a list of available JSON fields. I'm using gh version 2.4.0.

@AlexFlint The latest version is 2.55.0, I recommend upgrading.
